# Java executed statement not returning string data in resultset

Tags: sql, string, oracle, resultset

I have a simple SQL code that returns one record but when I execute it from Java, it does not return the string portions of the record, only numerical.  The fields are VARCHAR2 but do not get extracted into my resultset.  Following is the code.  The database connectivity portion has been edited out for posting in the forum but it does connect.  I have also attached the output.  Any guidance would be appreciated as my searches on the web have returned empty.  -Greg

```
package testsql;

import java.sql.*;

public class TestSQL {

    String SQLtracknbr;
    int SQLtracklength;
    int numberOfColumns;
    String coltypename;
    int coldispsize;
    String SQLschemaname;

  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
  {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracam.corp.mot.com:1522:oracam";

        String SQLcode = "select DISTINCT tracking_number from sfc_unit_process_track where tracking_number = 'CAH15F6WW9'";

        System.out.println(SQLcode);

        Connection conn =
         DriverManager.getConnection(url,"report","report");

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
      try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(SQLcode)) {

          ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rset.getMetaData(); 

          while (rset.next()) {

        int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        boolean b = rsmd.isSearchable(1);
        String coltypename = rsmd.getColumnTypeName(1);
        int coldispsize = rsmd.getColumnDisplaySize(1);
        String SQLschemaname = rsmd.getSchemaName(1);

        String SQLtracknbr = rset.getString(1);
        int SQLtracklength = SQLtracknbr.length();

        if (SQLtracknbr == null)
              System.out.println("NULL**********************.");
        else
           System.out.println("NOT NULL.");

        System.out.println("numberOfColumns = " + numberOfColumns);
        System.out.println("column type = " + coltypename);
        System.out.println("column display size = " + coldispsize);
        System.out.println("tracking_number = " + SQLtracknbr);
        System.out.println("track number length = " + SQLtracklength);
        System.out.println("schema name = " + SQLschemaname);
          }
      }
    System.out.println ("*******End of code*******"); 
}
}
```

The result of what is executed in Java is below:

```
run:

select DISTINCT tracking_number from sfc_unit_process_track where tracking_number = 'CAH15F6WW9'

NOT NULL.
numberOfColumns = 1
column type = VARCHAR2
column display size = 30
tracking_number =
track number length = 0
schema name =
*******End of code*******
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: At a guess, maybe when you use 1 in that while loop, you're supposed to be using 0?

Comment: What happens if you run that query in SQL*Plus as the same user you're connecting with from Java? Do you have any virtual private database policies in place, maybe? What database and driver versions are you using, just in case you have a known problematic combination.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - the 1 is referencing the correct column.  Numbering starts at 1 and not zero.  I have another query, a modification of this one, that pulls more columns and the same issue...no strings returned.

Comment: @AlexPoole-  Server is Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production.  I have ojdbc7.jar loaded on my machine.  If I run my query using PL/SQL, I get the correct result (well data returned by the SQL that is).

Comment: Then it may be a compatibility issue; [ojdbc7 only seems to be supported for 12c](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03). Can you try it with a different driver version to verify if it works?

Comment: @AlexPoole - Alex.  Thank you for your input.  That is exactly what my issue was.  I put ojdbc6.jar and removed the ojdbc7.jar library and now all is fine with the exception of my query pulling the schema name from the meta data (but I don't really care about that).  I appreciate your recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by an incompatibility between the driver you're using, `ojdbc7.jar`, and the version of the database you're connecting to, 9i.

According to [the JDBC FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03) section "*What are the various supported Oracle database version vs JDBC compliant versions vs JDK version supported?*", the JDK 7/8 driver `ojdbc7.jar` that you're using is only support for Oracle 12c.

Oracle generally only support client/server versions two release apart (see [My Oracle Support note 207303.1](http://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1)), and the Oracle 12c and 9i client and server have never been supported either way around. JDBC is slightly different of course, but it may be related, as drivers are installed with the Oracle software.

You will have to upgrade your database to a supported version, or - perhaps more practically in the short term - use an earlier driver. The [Wayback Machine snapshot of the JDBC FAQ](http://web.archive.org/web/20130621013228/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html) from 2013 says the 11.2.0 JDBC drivers - which includes `ojdbc6.jar` and `ojcbd5.jar` - can talk to RDBMS 9.2.0. So either of those ought to work...